# Covert integer to date format in xdf file

Tags: r

I have problem converting my Visit (integer) date variable to date format in r revolution

```
xform <- function(data) { 
data$Visit <- as.Date(data$Visit, format="%Y%m%d")
return(data)
}
rxDataStep(inData = FactP_XDF, outFile = "testSample",
           transformFunc = xform , overwrite = TRUE)
```

however, I got following error

ERROR: The sample data set for the analysis has no variables.
Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 3756. ThreadID: 11568 Rethrowing.
Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 5249. ThreadID: 11568 Rethrowing.
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  ERROR: The sample data set for the analysis has no variables.

Comment: Do you an example of how your `data$Visit` is?

Comment: if it's an integer you need to specify `origin`, in the `as.Date()`  function